# Retrieve last value in a row of a specific column of multiple closed workbooks without opening

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of files in a worksheet, that are files in a subfolder of the current directory.

I need to retrieve the value of a specific cell (can change), in a specific sheet (constant).

Of 10 files that are in the subfolder and which all have a sheet called "resumen", I want to get the value of the last row in column G.

So far I have this

```
Sub read_data_from_file_WO_openning()

Dim outputs_address As String
Dim FolderName As String, wbName As String,  cValue As Variant
outputs_address = Sheets("lista_macro").Range("G2").Value
ruta_csv_output = ActiveWorkbook.Path & outputs_address

FolderName = ruta_csv_output
'select files to review
For Each file_analysis In Sheets("archivos_en_outputs").Range("I2", Range("I2").End(xlDown))
    wbName = file_analysis.Value

    cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile2(FolderName, wbName, "resumen", "G1")
    MsgBox (file_analysis & cValue) 'to see the values
Next file_analysis
End Sub


Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile2(ByVal wbPath As String, _
  wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant

    Dim arg As String
    If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
    arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
      wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

    GetInfoFromClosedFile2 = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

In range I2 to down I have my list of files.
The problem is that my "G1" only retrieves data of cell G1 of all files, and I need the last row of column G for each file.
Sometimes these files have 7 rows, others have 15. The number of rows can change but always is at least 2.

I know the problem is in cell reference, but I don't know how to change this to accomplish what I have said.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're trying to do without opening the workbook. In order to figure out what the last row in the file is, you're going to have to open it.

Comment: @StoneGiant it's keep of wonky but you can get the value without opening the file.

Comment: @TinMan, I agree but it really boils down to what you mean by 'opening'. For all intents and purposes, the external workbook has been 'opened' to peek at the value but it hasn't been Workbooks.Open'ed. We used to call this 'touching' a spreadsheet because you could open the file in C, drill down to your target and read it. For an XLSX, it has to be accessed, unZipped (or unRARed) then drilled down and read.

Comment: @Jeeped True, but  `'touching'` the workbook using `ExecuteExcel4Macro()` to retrieve  a single value is much faster than `Opening` a large workbook.

Comment: @TinMan, tbh, I've never tested nevermind used ExecuteExcel4Macro on an XLSX and my default save is for XLSB.

Comment: @Jeeped I tested it against a 76MB xls file. `CountA()` on such a large file was slow.

Comment: @TinMan, fwiw xlsb is smaller, loads faster and calculates faster. If you have to rip out a vba project, just saveas xlsx. Oh, and the default install is still 32-bit Office on a 64-bit OS; make sure you're on 64-bit Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there are no blank spaces in Column G, you can use ExecuteExcel4Macro with the WorksheetFunction CountA to find the last row.

```
Function getLastValueInColumnG(ByVal wbPath As String, wbName As String, wsName As String) As Variant
    Dim count As Long
    Dim Address As String
    Address = getExternalR1C1Address(wbPath, wbName, wsName, "G:G")
    count = ExecuteExcel4Macro("CountA(" & Address & ")")
    Address = getExternalR1C1Address(wbPath, wbName, wsName, "G" & count)
    getLastValueInColumnG = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Address)
End Function

Function getExternalR1C1Address(ByVal wbPath As String, wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As String
    If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
    getExternalR1C1Address = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
End Function
```

Comment: Outstanding!!! It was exactly what I needed. It works perfectly fine!!!

Comment: Yay..go me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach assuming you have limited number of rows in your output files (<1000 ?)

```
Option Explicit

Sub find_in_closed_files()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Fch As Range
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook: Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim Fld As String: Fld = Wb1.Path & Sheets("lista_macro").Range("G2").Value
    If Not Right(Fld, 1) = "\" Then Fld = Fld & "\"
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet: Set Ws1 = Wb1.Sheets(1)
    Dim Ws2 As Worksheet: Set Ws2 = Wb1.Sheets("tmp pull") 'This is a temp draft sheet to pull the data that you'll need to create

    For Each Fch In Ws1.Range("I2", Ws1.Range("I2").End(xlDown))
        Ws2.Cells.Clear
        Ws2.Range("G1:G999").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF('" & Fld & "[" & Fch.Value & "]resumen'!RC<>"""",'" & Fld & "[" & Fch.Value & "]resumen'!RC,"""")"
        Ws2.Range("G1:G999").Value2 = Ws2.Range("G1:G999").Value2
        MsgBox Ws2.Range("G9999").End(xlUp).Value
    Next Fch

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This leaves a formula in column G that will track the last text, number or date in column G of the resumen worksheet within the closed external workbooks.

```
Sub xlsxLastG()

    Dim i As Long, f As String

    With Worksheets("archivos_en_outputs")

        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
            'conform C:\Users\public\AppData\Documents\test.xlsb
            '     to 'C:\Users\public\AppData\Documents\[test.xlsb]resumen'!G:G
            f = .Cells(i, "I").Value
            f = Left(f, InStrRev(f, Chr(92))) & Chr(91) & Right(f, Len(f) - InStrRev(f, Chr(92)))
            f = Chr(39) & f & Chr(93) & "resumen'!G:G"

            .Cells(i, "G").Formula = _
              "=index(" & f & ", max(iferror(match(1e99, " & f & "), 0), iferror(match(""zzz"", " & f & "), 0)))"
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

`#N/A` errors would typically mean column G was blank; `#REF!` errors would indicate not existing workbook or no resumen worksheet within the referenced workbook.